# How do you fix a segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

When I run my code I keep getting a message that I have a segmentation fault. I did a core dump with the GDB and it told me that my problem is with p = p->next; int the function below. Can someone help me understand what I did wrong and how I can go about fixing it? I know that segmentation faults have something to do with incorrect use of pointers but I am not sure what is wrong with p = p->next.

```
int list_size(const list_t *h) {
node_t *p = *h;
int r = 0;
do {
    r += 1;
    p = p->next;
} while (p);
return r;
}
```

Comment: See [here for how to debug](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to post code that isn't working.

Comment: What value does p have at the start (just after `node_t *p = *h`)?

Comment: what is `list_t`?  (looks like it might be a nasty pointer typedef)

Comment: Since you already have `gdb`, just run the program with it and upon crashing and burning,  *look at your variables*.

Comment: Recommend assert: http://ptolemy.eecs.berkeley.edu/~johnr/tutorials/assertions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for null pointers before you use them.

Change

```
do {
    r += 1;
    p = p->next;
} while (p);
```

to

```
while (p)
{
    r += 1;
    p = p->next;
}
```

Comment: if that fixed it then you should mark  R sahu's answer right @SteveCohen